# Single Bulk Operation on several blocks

Tags: blocks, views

I would like to display on a single page several blocks generated by views and associate the same bulk operation to all of them so that the user only needs to click execute once.

Where would you start to achieve this ?

All ideas welcome.

Comment: You'll have to tell us more about what you're trying to achieve here. You might be able to do something with hook_block_view_alter.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a specific list of blocks you want to alter, [get their deltas](https://www.drupal.org/node/1051888) and invoke [hook_block_view_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_view_alter/7) in a custom module, as follows:

```
function YOURMODULE_block_view_alter(&$data, $block) {
  switch($block->delta) {
     case 'delta1':
     ...
     case 'deltaN':
       // alter the block in the required way by modifying the $data array
       break;
  }
 }
```

If you want to alter ALL blocks created by a particular module, say, views, do a switch on `$block->module`, instead, i.e.:

```
function YOURMODULE_block_view_alter(&$data, $block) {
      switch($block->module) {
         case 'views':
         case 'SomeOtherModule':
           // alter the block in the required way by modifying the $data array
           break;
      }
}
```

Bear in mind that hook_block_view_alter is called for ALL blocks, so if your site has lots of blocks, this may be a performance hit.

Comment: I create an admin page to select "today's favorites" nodes. Nodes are associated with a category taxonomy term and I want to display 1 block per category. For example, 1 block for Business nodes, 1 block for Health nodes... 

I can do that adding a bulk operation for each block which will add that checkbox to select "Today's favorites". But doing it this way will create 1 bulk operation per block, and the admin will have to Press Execute for each of them.

I would like to have that same display (1 block per category) but have only 1 Execute operation to alter all nodes selected on the page.